# Algorithm for calculating beta and eta for weibull

Tags: r, estimation, reliability, weibull-distribution

I am writing code for drawing weibull plot in R. There are already some libraries for weibull and they are excellent. But they require ready beta and eta values for calculation of weibull function. In regular practice it is calculated from actual plotting on weibull paper. But is there any algorithm for calculating beta and eta?

Comment: You are really asking for methods of estimating the parameters of a weibull distribution.  See for example https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/230109/comparing-approaches-of-mle-estimates-of-a-weibull-distribution